# Golden Gate don't sync all records

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I Have some OGG processes configured. For most of the tables the Initial Load (sourceistable - specialrun) replicates all the data.
For a small group of tables the Initial Load Extract stops without any error and with only partial data sync to the target.

The source database is an oracle 12c and the target is a SQL Server 2019.
The source and target tables as primary keys. The tables only has two fields, Primary key and a XML Type. I can't share the xml because it's confidential data.
The extract is as follow :

```
ADD EXTRACT TEST, SOURCEISTABLE
extract TEST
useridalias xyz
rmthost xyzhost, mgrport 7809
rmttask replicat, group TEST

TABLE ABC.XYZ;


ADD REPLICAT TEST, SPECIALRUN
replicat TEST
targetdb odbc, useridalias xyz
MAP ABC.XYZ, TARGET test.XYZ;
```

after the initial load, the `view report TEST` does not show any error. Can't see any error at ggserror.log too. There is no discard information. It just stops without any error. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT

I added the trace, and now can see the following :

```
processSelectLob: read LOB column COLUMN_NAME(1) with current byte length 50000 (fragment 25, length 2000).
2020-10-07 11:32:44.008 DEBUG|gglog.std.application | 2834 ggdbora/ocifetch.cpp | processSelectLob: actual length of LOB read for column COLUMN_NAME(1) is 50000.
2020-10-07 11:32:44.008 DEBUG|gglog.std.application | 2836 ggdbora/ocifetch.cpp | processSelectLob: **error: it can not be less than character length of LOB 52001**
```

Is there any way to manage this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might reside in the target database (SQL Server), [this might help you](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/resolve-length-of-lob-data-to-be-replicated-exceeds-maximum-65536-error-on-sql-server):

```
USE Database  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 ;   
RECONFIGURE ;   
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'max text repl size', -1 ;   
GO  
RECONFIGURE;   
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but the problem persist.

Comment: There is no error at the SQL Server side. I tried to see error logs using SSMS. 
only see error at OGG.

Comment: The error says that "it can not be less than 52001" and in fact your length is 50000. Maybe you have to change the minimum length side on Golden Gate side?

Comment: the length of the record is 52001, and I managed to replicate bigger records with more than 52001 of length.

Comment: If you read the message there is no problem with records >52001. The problem is when the records are <52001 and in fact your is 50000 which is less then 52001. So no problems with big messages. Yes, definitely problems with small messages

Comment: No, there is lot of records with less